# How to add multi-column text with variable length as a slide into a slick.js caroussel

Tags: javascript, html, css, multiple-columns, slick.js

For a project I need to build a slider, that takes images, local videos and text that will be loaded from a json file. The slides have a fixed height and the content should resize to match this. The text will be a multi paragraph document and should split to multiple columns when the height is reached.

I use [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) as a framework with the variable width attribute. The text-item uses column styles. A example can be found [here](https://codepen.io/vacuum_packed/pen/bzjZNv). Only works in Firefox.

```js
$(".your-class").slick({
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  centerMode: true,
  variableWidth: true
});
```

```css
.text-container {
  height: 600px;
  width: 1000px;

}
.text-item {
  max-height: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
  column-count: auto;
  column-width: 300px;
  column-fill: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="your-class">
  <div class="text-container">
    <div class="text-item">
      --Long text that doesn't fit into one column--
    </div>
  </div>
  <img class="item" alt="" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
  <img class="item" alt="" src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" />
  <img class="item" alt="" src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" />
</div>
```

Without a width in the text-container the next slide begins at the column-width instead of the text block. How do I force slick.js to use the full multi column text without knowing the complete width?

Comment: Your codepen example doesn’t seem to reproduce what you say is happening, at least not for me in Chrome. The `.text-item` element gets a width of 20,000px, I don’t see anything shrinking to the column width of 300px.

Comment: I am not sure if something like that is supposed to work with the variableWidth setting; I think you might need to calculate and set the width yourself somehow.

Comment: I developed it using Firefox so it seems only to work in it, but that's ok for me. Regarding the other part I don't have a clue how to realize it.